# How to replace php function with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to AJAX here. How can i replace the initial php function after the action of ajax is execute? I have found that the page will not refresh after the action is execute. 
Here is the code:

javascript

```
function set_ddm(another_data) {
    var result = $.ajax({
        url: '../display/ea_form_header.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'set_ddm',
            Data_store: another_data,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

        }
    }).responseText;
}
```

php code

```
<td>
<?php 
//initial function (customized drop down)
print ddm_jsfunc_employee("employee_list",$employee_list)

set_ddm(data);

if($_POST['action'] =='set_ddm') {
    $employee_list=$_POST['Data_store'];    

    $employee_list_decoded = json_decode($employee_list,true);              

//expected this function to replace the initial function after ajax was called
print ddm_jsfunc_employee("employee_list",$employee_list_decoded);
} ?>
</td>
```

I expect the function will replace the initial function and show in the main page but it only show in console after ajax(page aren't refresh to show it). Is there any wrong with the code or any solution for this? (the ddm_jsfunc_employee must be there to print the drop down) 
thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly you want to do with your AJAX? Because in `success` callback, only `console.log` is written. 
All the stuffs to do after success should be within that callback.

Comment: You should manipulate DOM with jQuery inside that success function. Now you're just forwarding the data to console, but instead you probably want to `.append()` it into some html element on your page (also `.remove()` or `.empty()` old data, if you intend to replace something with this new one).

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar I wanted to print the function of ddm_jsfunc_employee() but how can I do it in ```success``` as the function is written in php ?

Comment: The `data` variable is the response that you get from your server side code.
Use this variable and put it where you want.

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar is that means the ```data``` must in html form?

Comment: data can be as html or as an array or an object. It dependa on you, how tou want to utilise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ajax success callback you have to set that response in the html to view on web page.

like this:

```
$('.elementClass').html(response);
```

i hope this will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding about what [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is, it is not something to replace your PHP code with, but to asynchronously get data and update your webpage without reloading.

Let's first take a look at the [.ajax function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) specifically interesting for us now is the `.done()` callback method, because JavaScript does the request realtime (async) JavaScript does not know when the request is done. But it allows us to specify a function inside the `.done` for it to call when it is done.

A really simple example would be:

```
$.ajax('https://stackoverflow.com')
.done(function(data) {
    // We can do what we want with the data here.
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now when the request is done the function we defined in `.done` will be called, in this case a simple log. But you would want to change this to a function that updates your HTML.

I also see you are calling JavaScript functions in your PHP, this will not work as PHP runs on your server but JavaScript runs in your browser. (Unless you use node or the likes)

Just a tip; it is advised to place JavaScript at the bottom of your HTML page as JavaScript is blocking content. (proper link explaining needed here)
Meaning your browser will stop parsing the HTML and run the JavaScript as it finds it.

Long story short, if you want to replace the PHP code, you would have to remove it. Make a PHP script which gives you your data. AJAX call it and then use `.done` or `success` and update your webpage from there.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip! Will try to reform my structure of my code